# Running 5V status LEDs on 24V circuit?

Tags: voltage, led, solid-state-relay

So I have a relatively simple circuit. I have a little float sensor that is connected to a 24V circuit and when that float sensor is triggered (water is too low in the container) it connects the circuit, which triggers a solid state relay to connect a 120VAC circuit to turn on a pump which pumps up the container until the float sensor disconnects. I would like to add a status LED on the side of the 24V, probably on the low side of the SSR, so that I know when it is pumping and when it is off. Is there any clever way to add a 5V LED onto this circuit, or do I just need to bite the bullet and buy a 24V LED? I've included my circuit below:

[image]

UPDATE:

Here is the updated schematic based on the help I've received:[image]

Comment: LEDs are not voltage, but current devices. There is no such a thing as "5V" LED, unless it is not a pure LED.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I don't actually have a spec sheet for these LEDs, they just came in a packet recommended for running from the I/O pins of an Arduino so I assumed they were 5V. So since there is minimal current running on this circuit what could I do to ensure they run safely?

Comment: Series resistor. Look around this site about how to match a resistor to LED, there are hundreds of related questions.

Comment: And your solid-state relay is backwards. The LED side of an SSR is the input, not the output.

Comment: The fact OP is using SSR's , drawn incorrectly, means he needs more help

Comment: Ah I thought it was backwards but the program I used labeled that as the load side which mixed me up. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @clifgray you need any LED with any diode reversed across it or 2 LEDs reversed in parallel with a series R of 2.2k for ~ 10mA then either LEd operates in either polarity and self protected across pump. capiche?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 how does the extra diode that is reversed protect it?

Comment: LEDs are rated for -5V MAX and the Vf of one diode protects the Vr of the other

Comment: pumps induce a negative spike on turn off. that's why it's needed and your SSR is likely a series pass high side switch using a Mosfet which may have a reverse output clamp zener diode internally.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 so it would be the same as a flyback diode? Would I need that if the LED is on the 24V side? If the SSR is optically isolated could the negative spike cross it onto the 24V circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, take note that your SSR is drawn backwards in your schematic.

Most LED's are current driven devices that will illuminate properly with 10 to 15 mA of current. When this much current passes through the LED, it generally has about 2 volts across it. This means that you need a resistor that will have the other 22 volts across it when ~10 mA of current is passing through it.

A simple Ohm's law calculation of 22 volts / 0.010 amps shows that a resistor of ~ 2200 ohms should do the job. Then calculate the wattage rating of the resistor as 0.010 amps * 0.010 amps * 2200 ohms and you have 0.22 watts. For reliability sake, you should use at least a 0.5 watt resistor.

The LED is connected in parallel with the LED of your SSR with the same polarity as the LED in the SSR (recalling that your schematic shows it backwards).

Comment: Thanks Glenn. So I've added a new schematic representing what I took to be your answer. Does that match with what you intended?

Comment: Yes that should do it.